# Infinite "loop" or "while let" are the same in terms of performances?

Tags: loops, rust, while-loop

In the below code I'm receiving from a channel and based on some logic I return `Option<Message>`.

```rust
impl Listener {
    pub async fn receive(&mut self) -> Option<Arc<Message>> {
        if let Ok(message) = self.receiver.recv().await {
            if message.team_id == self.team_id {
                println!("this is the issue, I'm returning None and it closes the stream! block");
                return None;
            }

            Some(message)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

When I receive that message in the axum handler I'm using an infinite `loop` like this:

```rust
 let res = async_stream::stream! {
    loop {
        if let Some(msg) = receiver.receive().await {
            yield Ok(sse::Event::default().data(msg));
        }
    }
};
```

but I'm afraid that the infinite `loop` can be dangerout for performances.

#### First question

Is it ok to use infinite loop like this? Is it always trying to get data?

I'm scaring because I'll have tons of this function alive concurrently.

#### Second question

Is the `while let` version the same as the infinite `loop`?

I tried to use the below code but it closes the stream if the message is `None`. Why?

Should I use `Result<>` instead? And how?

```rust
let s = async_stream::stream! {
    while let Some(msg) = receiver.receive().await {
            yield Ok(sse::Event::default().data(msg));
    }
};
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45f88d93b198a812877f9500f4daab52)

Comment: The `while let` and `loop { if let }` versions are almost identical, apart of the fact that the `while let` stops if `receive` returns `None`, while the `loop` version locks up. Add an `else {break;}` to your `if let`, then they are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while let Some(msg) = receiver.receive().await {
    yield Ok(sse::Event::default().data(msg));
}
```

This means, loop as long as the return value of `receive()` is `Some(...)`. If it is `None`, then exit the loop.

So if you translate it to a `loop` version, it would be this:

```
loop {
    if let Some(msg) = receiver.receive().await {
        yield Ok(sse::Event::default().data(msg));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

The big question here is what you are trying to communicate with a `None`. By default, `None`s in `receive` indicate that the stream ended. In that case, using the `while let` makes perfect sense, because it is desired that the loop stops after the stream ended.

In your case, however, you have this code:

```rust
if message.team_id == self.team_id {
    println!("this is the issue, I'm returning None and it closes the stream! block");
    return None;
}
```

It returns a `None` in case the message is not what you desired. That one now creates mixed signals for the outside - in one case, `None` is used to communicate that the stream is over, and in the other case, it communicates that the message should be ignored.

You need to separate those two cases. There are two ways I could think of:

- Introduce another `Option`, like `Option<Option<..>>`, where the outer `Option` communicates the end of the stream, and the inner `Option` communicates that the message should be ignored.
- Don't return from your `receive` function until the stream is either over or a valid message got received.

I personally would go with the second option. I'll further simplify the code by using `.ok()?` to convert the `Result` to an `Option` and propagate `None`.

```rust
impl Listener {
    pub async fn receive(&mut self) -> Option<Arc<Message>> {
        loop {
            let message = self.receiver.recv().await.ok()?;
            if message.team_id != self.team_id {
                return Some(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, use the `while let` version because `None` now again indicates that your connection ended, and in that case it is in fact dangerous to use a `loop` because it would spin with 100% CPU power forever. (because `receive()` would continuously and without waiting time return `None` over and over again)

---

To answer your concern about `loop` - `loop` itself does nothing bad, just like `while`. It's only bad if it's a busy loop, meaning there is no waiting point inside of the loop. But your loop has an `.await` where it constantly hangs, so no CPU power is wasted. (until the `.await` doesn't actually wait any more, like when the connection of the `receive()` function is closed)

---

Additional remark:

In case your situation is a little more complicated and you need multiple places where the processing of the current package gets aborted, you can use a combination of `loop` and `continue` to achieve that cleanly. Like so:

```rust
impl Listener {
    pub async fn receive(&mut self) -> Option<Arc<Message>> {
        loop {
            let message = self.receiver.recv().await.ok()?;

            if message.team_id == self.team_id {
                // Skip the current message
                continue;
            }

            // Return the message if we didn't hit any `continue`s
            return Some(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately my code for skipping messages is not so easy and I need to early return many times. So I think I'll go with the first option you suggested.

Comment: @FredHors adapting even a complex, early returning filtering would be as easy as just replacing every early `return None`/`return Some(None)` with a `continue` in the `loop` version of this answer.

Comment: @FredHors I agree with cafce25, I think there's rarely the situation where the first option is really necessary. In case you are not familiar (although I guess you already know), `continue` says "restart the loop from the beginning", which is exactly what you would need in that situation.

Comment: @FredHors I added an example to my answer to demonstrate how that would look like

Comment: Thanks. But how to handle an `Err` from `.await.ok()?` in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; what exactly do you have in mind when you say *'handle the `Err`'*? How would you want your code to react to an error? What would an appropriate action be?

Comment: For example print the error...

Comment: @FredHors Then, you can use a `match` instead of `.ok()?`, like so: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/815f5604474676ba5bff2940e73fb845. I recommend reading the [respective chapter in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is one subtle difference that I think is very important and nobody mentioned it.

`if let`, `if while`, and `match` will hold all temporary values, until the end of associated block.

As can be seen from these two implementations of thread pool worker.

```
impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();
            // Lock is dropped here, other workers can lock the receiver and receive jobs.
            job();
        });
        Worker { id, thread }
    }
}
```

```
impl Worker {
    fn new(id: usize, receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Job>>>) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() {
                // Lock is still being held, other workers can not receive jobs.
                job();
                // Lock is dropped here
            }
        });

        Worker { id, thread }
    }
}
```

The only mention of this I have found was on https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html, if anybody could point to some more reading on this, that would be great.

Comment: What are you suggesting?